# R: How to determine if a function is an S3 method overriding a generic

Tags: r, methods

I want to determine if an arbitrary function is an S3 method overriding a generic function. If so, I would want to identify the generic as next step.

**The Problem**

I need something like `HasGeneric(AMethod)` that tells me whether my argument `AMethod` is a method overriding some generic. Or even better  `FindGeneric(AMethod)` that returns the according generic for `AMethod`.

The first idea I had was parsing the function name because the pattern "generic.class" is recommended to be used to name methods. Example:

- `print` is the generic.
- `print.aov` overrides `print` for the S3 class `aov`.

But string parsing is not without ambiguities: `all.equal.data.frame` (in the dplyr package).

Furthermore, the pattern isn't even mandatory anymore. Look at this:

```r
a <- 1:5
class(a) <- "SomeTestClassOfMineNotToBeConfused"

# Register some arbitrarily named method as override for print
thisismyaprinter <- function(x) cat("I am A okay")
.S3method("print", "SomeTestClassOfMineNotToBeConfused", thisismyaprinter) # register as override for `print`

methods(class = "SomeTestClassOfMineNotToBeConfused") # now `print` is in the list of methods
#> [1] coerce      initialize  print       show        slotsFromS3
#> see '?methods' for accessing help and source code

print(a) # test works, too
#> I am A okay
```

As we all know, the output of a as simple vector 1:5 would be:

```r
print(a <- 1:5)
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

**Tried solutions**

All functions that I found to investigate methods either assume that I know the name of the generic or the class (which I don't). I could (of course)

1. go over all available generics using `.knownS3Generics`.
2. Get their methods with `methods()`
3. And search them with the function name that I have.

That would not only be slow. It would not even work. When I looked up the methods for `print` in my example above I got this:

```r
methods(print)
#> [201] ...
#> [202] print.SomeTestClassOfMineNotToBeConfused*           
#> [203] ...
```

R did register the method with the "generic.class" name pattern. But it is not possible to access this:

```r
print.SomeTestClassOfMineNotToBeConfused(a)
#> Error in print.SomeTestClassOfMineNotToBeConfused(a): konnte Funktion "print.SomeTestClassOfMineNotToBeConfused" nicht finden
```

... which means R could not find the function `print.SomeTestClassOfMineNotToBeConfused`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getDispatchMethodS3` form `R.methodsS3`

```
R.methodsS3::getDispatchMethodS3("print" ,
            "SomeTestClassOfMineNotToBeConfused")(a)

#> I am A okay
```

Comment: For that I'd still need to know the generic and the class which I do not. I only have `thisismyaprinter()`.

Comment: By the way, your answer still gave me the hint to at least take a look at `R.methodsS3`. Unfortunately it only searches for the "generic.class" name pattern: first `fcnName <- paste(methodName, className, sep=".")` and then it calls `getAnywhere(fcnName)` to find out if the object exists. So it would not know what to do with e method like `thisismyaprinter()`.